# What is the easiest way to create an incremental array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I just would like to know what is the easiest way to create an incremental array?

```
$myarray = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4, 'test5', 'test6', 'test7', 'test8');
```

Of course I can use a "for" loop...

```
for ($i=1;$i<=8;$i++){
    $myarray[] = 'test'.$i;
}
```

...but do you know if I can do better with a native php function (or something like that)?

Comment: What is the point of this question?  What's wrong with the loop?

Comment: I think your way is pretty ok. It does what it's suposed to, with minimun resources. Just leave it like that

Comment: Ok, thank you Daniel for your answer.

Comment: range('a', 'z'); generates an array containing all chars from a-z, range(0, 5); an array containing all numbers from 0 to 5. ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method using [`array_map()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) along with [`range()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
$array = array_map(function($n){ return "test" . $n;}, range(1, 8));

print_r($array);
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3
    [3] => test4
    [4] => test5
    [5] => test6
    [6] => test7
    [7] => test8
)
```

I'm not sure I would choose to use this over a plain old loop like your example though.  The only real benefit is the ease of use `range()` adds over an incremental `for` loop. The added complexity of `array_map()`'s anonymous function probably isn't worth it for a case this simple.

Comment: Agree with Michael. Was looking at array_fill (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php), but it only pre-populates with a static value.